# Couldn't load JVM and says cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, rhel, java

created a brand new Linux VM on azure cloud.  Installed JDK 1.8 and setup the JAVA_HOME path also.

When running a vendor provided command it says

```
Error 58000: Couldn't load JVM: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

We raised this to the vendor and they mentioned that it is a JAVA error and nothing to do with the product.

How on a brand new VM the reference of java-11-openjdk-amd64 is coming? Ideally it should refer the libjvm.so that is located under jdk1.8 folder right.

How is that a java issue... I am bit confused and how this can be fixed

Comment: It looks like the command is referring to the Java 11 executable, and not the Java 8 executable that you want. Are you running the command without a full path, as in `java -jar ...`? If so, can you try using the complete path to the Java 8 executable?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after complete uninstall restart and reinstall of JDK 1.8